# Plot image intensity variation in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to plot how the intensity from an image changes as a linear graph (see the code below). I have x,y and the intensity data for each pixel. Now I want to plot x,y and the intensity, showing how the intensity changes, for each pixel. The image dimension is 70X10, the value of intensity is 700.

```
image= cv2.imread("DSC_1141.jpg") print('x',image[1]) for i in range(0, 
(image.shape[0])): for j in range(0,(image.shape[1])): d=image[i][j] 
data.insert(count,d) count = count +1 x=image[0] y=image[1]
```

Comment: This is the code 
image= cv2.imread("DSC_1141.jpg")
print('x',image[1])
for i in range(0,(image.shape[0])):
    for j in range(0,(image.shape[1])):
        d=image[i][j]
        data.insert(count,d)
      
        count = count +1
x=image[0]
y=image[1]

Comment: please reformat your code

Comment: From what you wrote in your question, you are trying to plot the actual image: the intensity at each pixel. If you just want to show intensity variation in one axis, you need to either stick to a given row or column in the image, or calculate an aggregation function for each row/column, like mean, median, or whatever gives you the representation you are looking for. Can you please clarify what you would like to achieve?